# Query the AddMethod field containing the SalesforceSubscriber value

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

currently I'm working on identifying the contacts that are in Marketing Cloud and came from the Marketing Cloud Connector.

If I query the _ListSubscribers, it will only show the following values for the Addmethod column:

```
Unknown
WebApplication
API
Imported
DataExtensionSend
```

However, if I access to the All Subscribers list, the AddMethod column will also show a "SalesforceSubscriber" value. The query I'm using is as follows:

```
select
    SubscriberID,
    SubscriberKey,
    EmailAddress,
    AddMethod 
from
    ent._ListSubscribers
where
    ListID = '101'
```

My question is: how can I have that value within the results I'm getting after querying? I was also thinking about creating a Mobile Connect list adding a Add Method field-based filter. However, I can't find a way to add that field in the conditions.

Appreciate your comments and suggestions. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Add method will be "SalesforceSubscriber" (in the UI) when the send is done to Salesforce Report/Campaigns and Salesforce Data Entry source and TriggeredSend from Salesforce.

In `_ListSubscribers` data view, the "Unknown" value is the corresponding one to "SalesforceSubscriber". SF told me that this due to the jointype for this value in their backend is not decoded in the Data View but they intended to implement it in the future.

Note: when the send is done from the sources I mentioned above, it won't be added immediately but take some time to be added into the `_ListSubscribers` data view.

---

To include this value in the query:

```
SELECT
    SubscriberID,
    SubscriberKey,
    EmailAddress,
CASE
    WHEN AddMethod = 'Unknown' THEN 'SalesforceSubscriber'
    ELSE AddMethod
END AS AddMethod
FROM
    ENT._ListSubscribers
```